# Index for all vertices in Neo4j

Tags: indexing, neo4j

I need to create a unique index across any vertex, irrespective of label, in Neo4j.

I can do the following, but it would not guarantee global uniqueness:

`CREATE CONSTRAINT
    ON (x:myType1)
    ASSERT x.identifier IS UNIQUE`

The above would allow (x:myType1) and (y:myType2) to have the same `identifier`.

Is there any way I could implement a globally unique uniqueness constraint?

Comment: neo4j gives each node a globally unique ID (but after a node is deleted its ID can be used again for a new node). You can use the `ID(node)` function to get the ID for a node. It is not clear from your question if this ID is good enough for your needs.

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately, I forgot to mention, I can`t reuse any deleted IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be better ways, but I just seem to have found one: using another label.

`CREATE (v:label1:global {identifier:"12345")`

And have the global uniqueness constraint only set against the global label:

`CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (g:global) ASSERT g.identifier IS UNIQUE`